# How to get Android MediaSession take the playback speed into account when showing the progress

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I have an Android app which plays some content.
I'm initializing a MediaSession object with the following information:

```
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
                mediaSession.setPlaybackToLocal(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 PlaybackStateCompat.Builder sessionState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
                sessionState.setActions(PLAYBACK_STATE_TRANSPORT_CONTROL_FLAGS);
                mediaSession.setPlaybackState(sessionState.build());
                mediaSession.setCallback(BuildMediaSessionCallback(context, mediaSession));
 PlaybackStateCompat.Builder sessionState = new PlaybackStateCompat.Builder();
 sessionState.setActions(getSessionStateActions(mediaSession));

 sessionState.setState(playbackState, position, speed);
 mediaSession.setPlaybackState(sessionState.build());

mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

Everything works fine. I can control the playback from my car BT receiver, the file metadata are published, however the progress bar/time is updated as if the provided playabck speed was 1.0x even though I'm sending values like 3.0x

The only way I'm able to update the progressbar properly is to call mediaSession.setPlaybackState(...) every seconds with the new playback position.
It looks like mediaSession isn't taking the speed parameter into account.
Does someone know how to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing it correctly, assuming `speed` is set to `3` in that case:

`sessionState.setState(playbackState, position, speed);`

The trouble sounds like it's on the UI side, where it isn't taking into account the playback speed when calculating playback position.

```
long timeDelta = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - state.getLastPositionUpdateTime();
long currentPosition = (state.getPosition() + (timeDelta * state.getPlaybackSpeed()));
```